# How to warn/error when a struct is padded?

Tags: struct, rust, padding

In certain unusual cases it may be a requirement that a struct isn't padded *(so the memory of the struct is ensured not to contain uninitialized bytes for example)*.

While it's possible to use `#[repr(packed)]`, this means you may have members which aren't optimally aligned for access.

In C, some software uses manual padding, where GCC's `-Wpadded` can be used to warn if the struct is padded.

Is there a way to warn/error when a struct is padded?
Or some way to ensure manually padded structs don't have any padding?

---

The closest thing to this I could come up with is to define the struct twice, pack one, then check if the sizes differ, but this is a kludge.

With some careful use of `include` it may be possible to avoid actually writing out the struct twice, but it's still a last-resort.

Comment: *this means you may have members which aren't optimally aligned for access.* => My tests on the latest x86_64 processors hint there's no longer a penalty for unaligned access; could still be an issue with unaligned SIMD types though.

Comment: Even though I realize I can probably *get away* with packing all my structs, I don't want to try port my software to another platform and run into some performance hit because packing happened not to matter for the one I'm currently on. It shouldn't be _that_ hard to do this, as stated in the question, some way already exists, its just not that nice.

Comment: Note that another platform may mean another ABI, and therefore another memory layout; so, in any case, porting may be an issue. Is your requirement strictly about not having uninitialized bytes or do you want to warn about padding for other reasons as well? (the two could have vastly different answers)

Comment: Or crashes. Other architectures aren't generally so forgiving about unaligned access.

Comment: @matthieu-m, I suspect *why* I don't want padding is outside the scope of the question and would lead to an overly spesific answer. If Rust can't do this, or if the kludge I suggested is the only way... (without using unstable features). Then probably best just to answer that this isn't supported.

Comment: I'm just making sure we're not facing a X/Y problem; it would be silly for you to get stuck with the kludge you suggested when there's an elegant solution for the *underlying* question you never asked :)

Comment: Might have a separate compile step with `-Z print-type-sizes` and grep for padding?

Comment: You can write a lint that checks the `Layout` of the type for padding.

Comment: There is [generated documentation for the rustc API for the memory Layout of its types](https://manishearth.github.io/rust-internals-docs/rustc/ty/layout/enum.Layout.html) and an [example of rust-clippy checking the memory Layout of types](https://github.com/Manishearth/rust-clippy/blob/4b29f9a36478575bd174f388ad3cfbef4a84d0cc/clippy_lints/src/large_enum_variant.rs#L67).